# do we need to apply ScrollView in container in react native to make it scroll-able for all size phones?

Tags: react-native

If i make my application screen on nexus4 emulator screen and wanted to see it on small screen phones, would it be necessary to use scrollview instead of View in react-native.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases yes, because scaling everything according to the screen size will make the app elements look extremely tiny on some devices and text will be hard to read. I had a similar issue where I scaled every screen according to the device resolution and customers complained about not being able to read on small devices. 
What I did was wrap such screens in a ScrollView, then put a View inside it with a `minHeight: screenHeight` then put elements with flexbox and fixed size inside it. This way it would fit most screens perfectly and on smaller ones it would still look good enough. You should experiment a little to see what works best for your app.